# Open Sans Condensed Light not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-font-api

I have downloaded the Open Sans Condensed Light font from Google Web Fonts, and also attached their CSS code:

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300&subset=greek-ext&v2'
      rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

But every browser other than Firefox, shows exact font family i.e. it looks fine in IE, Chrome, Safari, but not in Firefox.

Here is my CSS and the HTML code:

```css
h2.title-border {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.heading-sub {
    background: #000;
    font-family: "Open Sans Condensed Light";
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 32px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

**HTML**:

```html
<h2 class="title-border"><span class="heading-sub">About Us</span></h2>
```

Can you please suggest, how should I fix Firefox regarding this?

Comment: so you are using a custom font in ur code.. Have you imported the font in your css???

Comment: Why are you capitalizing all the names except your own?

Comment: yes.. I have imported the font and put the code in the head section as follows...

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed">

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the API, you should be calling the font like this

`<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:light&v1' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

The *light* variant needs to be called specifically, i.e. `:light`.

The other browsers are probably ignoring the `Light` in your stylesheet and giving you the `Open Sans Condensed` you asked for in the API call.

[See here](http://www.google.com/webfonts/family?family=Open%20Sans%20Condensed&subset=latin#code)

Comment: Hello there... thanks for above answer.. its working fine in all browser even in IE 8, but NOT IN IE9. Can you please resolve it ?

Comment: I have the same problem with FF and when used this approach it did not help me

Comment: The  [Google Fonts website](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans+Condensed?selection.family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300) recommends:

`Open+Sans+Condensed:300` and 

`font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;` in the css.

Answer (score 6):

Condensed is the "style" of the "Open Sans" font, not part of the name. This worked for me.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:Condensed" />


.selector
{
    font-family:'Open Sans';
    font-style:condensed;
}
```

Comment: It's `font-stretch: condensed;`. `font-style: condensed;` won't work.

Comment: The  [Google Fonts website](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans+Condensed?selection.family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300) specifically recommends:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">` in the header

`font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;` in the css.

Answer (score 3):

I must have tried a gazillion variations to get this work. I am trying to get Open Sans Condensed embedded into a pdf via WKHtmlToPdf.

I think it is important that you download and install the Open Sans Condensed ttf directly from google and install it. It is also important to reboot to allow other services access after install. I downloaded the ttf from font-squirrel originally and condensed was listed as "Open Sans" in windows/fonts, which is wrong, if you look after the google install it is listed as "Open Sans Condensed Light" so even google's `local('Open Sans Cond Light')` script is wrong.

As mentioned before you need to be explicit with the stretch and weights, so this is what has worked for me:

```
    @font-face { 
     font-family: 'Open Sans'; 
     font-style: normal; 
     font-weight: 400; 
     src: local('Open Sans');
    }

    @font-face { 
     font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed'; 
     font-stretch:condensed; 
     font-style: normal; 
     font-weight: 300; 
     src: local('Open Sans Condensed Light');
    }

@@font-face { font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed Bold'; font-stretch:condensed; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; src: local('Open Sans Condensed'), local('Open Sans Condensed Bold');}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make the font work for IE8-IE9  you have to use a EOT font file,
On this page you can download the font as a webkit:
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans-condensed

Answer (score 1):

You have to refer to Google CSS. See their [QuickStart Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/getting_started.html#Quick_Start).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed">
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably ought to use `font-stretch: condensed` ([see Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-stretch)).

For example, change your `.heading-sub` CSS as follows:

```
.heading-sub {
    background:#000;
    font-family:"Open Sans";
    font-stretch: condensed;
    font-weight:300;
    text-transform:none;
    font-size:32px;
    padding:0 15px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    color:#fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Make use of Google Fonts Open Sans in the various styles:

Click on this link -> https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans and then click on ***Open Open Sans*** in Google Fonts.

Under option 3 and 4 you will find the html link to use in your header as well as the CSS style usage.

Answer (score 0):

for Firefox:
My problem solved after I added to CSS this line:

**font-stretch: condensed;**

You should use Google generated code, mine was:
**http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>**

as I am using 700 and 300 weights.

CSS:
**font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
font-weight:700;
font-stretch: condensed;**

Answer (score 0):

it appears that all the browsers are somehow using different definitions for at least this font. i had it installed on my site and been trying to figure how to make it look descent in all browsers, not just chrome and opera - as all others, that is firefox, ie and safari had those fonts screwed. until accidentally i made firefox see the font ok, but then chrome and opera got screwed. so that was when i realized that actually assigning the same font in two different ways solves the problem: if the browser's ok with the first definition, it won't look at the next one, otherwise it'll go for the second one. ah, the code itself:

```
font-family: open sans condensed light, open sans condensed;
```

i used it for assigning fonts to different divs. cheers, hope this helps - at least for me it was a major pain in the behind.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't works for me because the @import should be the first line in style.

Works:

```
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300');

    .myStyle {
    }
</style>
```

Doesn't works:

```
<style>
    .myStyle {
    }

    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300');
</style>
```