# Issue with rendering Open Sans Light on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, styles

I have no problem displaying html pages on IE and Chrome using Open Sans Light, however when using Firefox, it does not understand this type of fonts.

This is a .css sections defining my fonts:

```
 .txtName
 {
     margin-left: 18px;
     font-size: 20px;
     color: #0140be;
     font-family: 'Open Sans Light' !important;
     font-weight:normal;
     line-height: 1.4em;   
 }
```

This is the part of html file that need to be displayed the same on IE, Chrome and FF:

```
<div class="txtName-Main">
     <h1 class="txtName">Your pathway to success starts here</h1>
</div>
```

What can be the problem?

Thx

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532458/font-familyopen-sans-condensed-light ?

Comment: How are you loading the fonts? Also, your opening `h1` tag doesn't have the first `<` symbol.

Comment: I just have font in my system's folder. How should I load the fonts?

Comment: I used `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` and it does not help

Answer (score 5):

'Open Sans Light' is not a valid representation of the font-family.  The 'Light' (300 weight) version of 'Open Sans' is:

In the head of your document:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

In your CSS:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
```

Comment: That works, as well. Thx. But I also have another section in my code that need to use `'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif` with `font-weight:400` and that does not work

Comment: with Google Fonts, you can load several fonts into the one URL: "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,400,300".  Then, all you need to do is change the font-weight, font-style properties, etc.https://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse

Comment: The problem was solved with that approach. However, when I copied the code into some network location, Chrome and FF show styles, but IE does not. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is that possible to achieve all these without referring to googleapis?

Comment: From https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq : "Can I download the fonts on Google Fonts to my own computer?
Yes. To download the fonts, simply add fonts to your collection and click the "Download your Collection" link. You can download the fonts to use them for your mockups, in your documents or to host them on your own server."

Answer (score 0):

I see a few suggestions, But what worked for me is loading my fonts with:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:Light' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and in .css I had to use the following definition:

```
color: #0140be;
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-style: Light;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: normal;
```

So, instead of having:

`font-family: 'Open Sans Light'`

I used

```
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-style: Light;
```

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

it appears that all the browsers are somehow using different definitions for at least this font. i had it installed on my site and been trying to figure how to make it look descent in all browsers, not just chrome and opera - as all others, that is firefox, ie and safari had those fonts screwed. until accidentally i made firefox see the font ok, but then chrome and opera got screwed. so that was when i realized that actually assigning the same font in two different ways solves the problem: if the browser's ok with the first definition, it won't look at the next one, otherwise it'll go for the second one. ah, the code itself:

font-family: open sans condensed light, open sans condensed;

i used it for assigning fonts to different divs. cheers, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
```

Goes in the `<head>` element and downloads light and regular fonts

In css style: 
        ul, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, li, dd, dt, a{
            font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 300;
            font-style: normal;
sets up (most) elements for web-based font and a (local) fall back font. `font-style: normal` is default, so it is not required. (`Font-style:Light` is not valid property.)