# convert ggplot object into svg which use Open Sans Semibold font

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2, r-markdown

I would like to create a `ggplot` plot which use Open Sans Semibold font and then I want to convert this plot into `svg`. Finally include this in `rmarkdown` doc. the biggest problem is **to use Open Sans Semibold on the converted `ggplot` object on the browser.**

1. I used `svglite` to convert `ggplot` into `svg` and it works well.
2. I included Open Sans Semibold font in titles of axis (I stored all Open Sans family locally).
3. I created `rmarkdown` doc.

   ````
   ---
   title: ""
   output: html_document
   ---

   ```{r setup, include = FALSE}
   library(svglite)
   knitr::opts_chunk$set(
     dev = "svglite",
     fig.ext = ".svg"
   )
   ```

   ```{r, warning = F, message = F, echo = F}
   library(ggplot2)

   data(cars)

   ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, qsec, color = factor(cyl))) +
      geom_point() +
      theme(text = element_text(family = 'Open Sans'),
           axis.title = element_text(family = 'Open Sans Semibold'))

   ```
   ````

When I open this doc in the Chrome/Opera/Mozilla browser, the Open Sans Semibold does not show up. Instead Arial replaces it. However in Safari it works perfectly.
It turned out (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531399/issue-with-rendering-open-sans-light-on-firefox)) that there is a typical problem on those browsers with Open Sans Semibold and Light. In order to solve it rather than using semibold version, I use css `font-weight` with basic `'Open Sans', sans-serif`. And it works perfectly when I create a `<p>`.

````
---
title: ""
output: html_document
---

<style> 
      @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700);

      .text_basic {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      }

      .text_semibold {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 700;
      }
</style>

<p class = 'text_basic'> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, nisi quasi cupiditate, ratione, consequuntur adipisci reiciendis impedit, laborum tenetur qui neque nobis enim. Sunt 
</p>

<p class = 'text_semibold'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, nisi quasi cupiditate, ratione, consequuntur adipisci reiciendis impedit, laborum tenetur qui neque nobis enim. Sunt 
</p>

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(svglite)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
      dev = "svglite",
      fig.ext = ".svg"
)
```

```{r, warning = F, message = F, echo = F}
library(ggplot2)

data(cars)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, qsec, color = factor(cyl))) +
      geom_point() +
      theme(text = element_text(family = 'Open Sans'),
            axis.title = element_text(family = 'Open Sans Semibold'))

```
````

However this solution does not work on `ggplot` object, because it still use Open Sans Semibold font. In `ggplot` it is not possible to use `font-weight` because there is no such thing. Instead you can only use `face` argument but that option does not accept `numeric` values.

One workaround which I initially believe could work is to convert `ggplot` object into html code and then use `css` to manipulate the fonts on axis.

````
---
title: ""
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(svglite)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
      dev = "svglite",
      fig.ext = ".svg"
)
```

```{r, warning = F, message = F, echo = F}
library(ggplot2)

data(cars)

s <- svgstring()

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, qsec, color = factor(cyl))) +
      geom_point() +
      theme(text = element_text(family = 'Open Sans'),
            axis.title = element_text(family = 'Open Sans Semibold'))

htmltools::HTML(s())
invisible(
      dev.off()
)

```
````

In that case it is possible to detect `text` tags and manipulate them as I want to, but generated code is flat i.e. it is not easy to differatiate `text` tags related to the labels and to the titles.

So, anyone has idea to solve this problem?

Thanks anyone who read this last sentence. I tried to summarize my problem as short as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your ideas for a workaround seem straight forward approaches, and to make them work with the plot, you can use `gsub` to directly modify the HTML and set the `font-weight` of the style attribute of the text:

```
s <- svgstring()

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, qsec, color = factor(cyl))) +
      geom_point() +
      theme(text = element_text(family = 'Open Sans'),
            axis.title = element_text(family = 'Open Sans Semibold'))

gsub("font-family: Open Sans Semibold;", 
     "font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 700;", 
     htmltools::HTML(s()))
```