# How to render Open Sans Semibold in firefox without using font weight property

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts

Firefox is not rendering Open Sans semibold properly. But the same code in Chrome renders the font. Font is installed in my system. Is it possible to render it without using font weight property?

`<html>`
`<style>`
`p{`
`font-family:"Open Sans Semibold";` 
`}`
`</style>`
`<body>`
`<p >test</p>`
`</body>`
`</html>`

Comment: how do you load your font? similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532458/open-sans-condensed-light-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: The font is installed in the system. And it is visible in the Libre Office too.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying in `font-family` property passed in `font-weight` with a value of 600 if font has been installed.

Example:

```
p {
font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
font-weight:600;
}
```

Hope this works..

Comment: Yeah that works properly. But is it possible to do it with just specifying Open Sans Semibold in font family? Google Chrome renders it correctly.

Comment: I think you can't use the font-family property to specify the font weight for firefox. Use font-weight instead because it's jobs is used to specify the weight of the font.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
body{font-family:"Open Sans"}
h1{font-weight:400}
h2{font-weight:600}
h3{font-weight:700}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test one</h1>
  <h2>Test two</h2>
  <h3>Test three</h3>
</body>
</html>
```